# JavaScript: I can't instantiate a class

Tags: javascript, object, scope

I am trying to create an object-orientated app, but I can't reference or instantiate any classes I create. I've been following syntax taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes and other sources but nothing seems to work (I'm using online sandboxes).

In the below code, the second alert statement is never reached. Anyone know why? 
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/chokpjsd/16/#&togetherjs=jKAgOFu0og

**JavaScript**

```js
class Hero {
  constructor(heroName) {
    this.name = heroName;
  }

  get name() {
    return this.name;
  }

  set name(newName) {
    this.name = newName;
  }
}

function getHeros() {
  alert("hi");

  var hero1 = new Hero("Superman");

  alert("hi 2");

  alert(hero1.name);

  document.getElementById("HerosContainer").innerHTML = "<p>" + hero1.name + "</p>";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>
    Hello World!
  </h1>

  <button onclick="getHeros()">
    Get Heros
  </button>

  <div id="HerosContainer">

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that within `Hero`, you've defined `name` as an accessor property, but within the accessor methods you're treating `name` as though it were a data property, which causes an infinite loop. If you look in your browser's devtools, you'll see a stack overflow exception.

```
class Hero {
    constructor(heroName) {
        this.name = heroName;
    }

    get name() {
        return this.name; // <=== Calls `get name` again, then again, then again...
    }

    set name(newName) {
        this.name = newName;  // <=== Calls `set name` again, then again, then again...
    }
}
```

If you want to define `name` as an accessor property, you have to store its value elsewhere. One popular choice is another property prefixed with an underscore to say "leave this alone in code outside the `Hero` class":

```
class Hero {
    constructor(heroName) {
        this._name = heroName;
// −−−−−−−−−−^
    }

    get name() {
        return this._name;
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
    }

    set name(newName) {
        this._name = newName;
// −−−−−−−−−−^
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
class Hero {
    constructor(heroName) {
        this._name = heroName;
    }

    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }

    set name(newName) {
        this._name = newName;
    }
}

function getHeros() {
    console.log("hi");

    var hero1 = new Hero("Superman");

    console.log("hi 2");

    console.log(hero1.name);

    document.getElementById("HerosContainer").innerHTML = "<p>" + hero1.name + "</p>";
}
```

```html
<h1>
 Hello World!
</h1>

<button onclick="getHeros()">
  Get Heros
</button>

<div id="HerosContainer">

</div>
```

But if you don't need it to be an accessor property, just remove the accessor methods entirely:

```
class Hero {
    constructor(heroName) {
        this.name = heroName;
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
class Hero {
    constructor(heroName) {
        this.name = heroName;
    }
}

function getHeros() {
    console.log("hi");

    var hero1 = new Hero("Superman");

    console.log("hi 2");

    console.log(hero1.name);

    document.getElementById("HerosContainer").innerHTML = "<p>" + hero1.name + "</p>";
}
```

```html
<h1>
 Hello World!
</h1>

<button onclick="getHeros()">
  Get Heros
</button>

<div id="HerosContainer">

</div>
```

---

Going back to accessors for a moment: If you have reason to make `name` an accessor property, soon you'll be able to save it in a truly private field on the instance via the [new private fields syntax](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields). (You can use that already if you transpile via Babel.) Here's an example that works on some modern browsers (including the latest Chrome, Chromium, Brave, and Chromium-based Edge):

```
class Hero {
    #name; // <== Declares the field (required for private fields)
    constructor(heroName) {
        this.#name = heroName;
// −−−−−−−−−−^
    }

    get name() {
        return this.#name;
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
    }

    set name(newName) {
        this.#name = newName;
// −−−−−−−−−−^
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
class Hero {
    #name;
    constructor(heroName) {
        this.#name = heroName;
    }

    get name() {
        return this.#name;
    }

    set name(newName) {
        this.#name = newName;
    }
}

function getHeros() {
    console.log("hi");

    var hero1 = new Hero("Superman");

    console.log("hi 2");

    console.log(hero1.name);

    document.getElementById("HerosContainer").innerHTML = "<p>" + hero1.name + "</p>";
}
```

```html
<h1>
 Hello World!
</h1>

<button onclick="getHeros()">
  Get Heros
</button>

<div id="HerosContainer">

</div>
```